# Get values by class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I tried for hours but could not find any solution.

Simplified my code looks like following.

**PHP :**

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT id FROM news ORDER BY position ASC") as $row)
    {
    ...
     <input type="text" class="_title" >
     Search: <input type="file" class="_file" >     
     <input type='button' class="_submit" value='Save' > 
    ...
    }
?>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("._submit").click(function(){

        ??  var _title = document.getElementById('_title'),
        ??  _file = document.getElementById('_file'); 

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('SelectedFile', _file.files[0]);
        data.append('title', _title.value); 
        ...
</script>
```

I don't know how to get the data by class. By ID it is working, but i can't use IDs, because there would be several same IDs because of the foreach loop.

Tried this as well without success:

```
var _file = document.getElementsByClassName('_file');
```

I hope somebody can help me.
Misch

Comment: The same you did in `php`, use loops :) You may not need many `submit` buttons I suppose..

Comment: `there would be several same IDs because of the foreach loop.` Note that duplicate `id` within a document will mean your HTML is invalid and can lead to unforeseen problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your elements in container div like

```
<?php
foreach($db->query("SELECT id FROM news ORDER BY position ASC") as $row)
    {
    ...
    <div class='container'>
     <input type="text" class="_title" >
     Search: <input type="file" class="_file" >     
     <input type='button' class="_submit" value='Save' > 
    </div>
    }
?>
```

Then use `.closest()` to traverse up the container. After wards you simply use `find` to get the desired elements.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("._submit").click(function(){
        var container = $(this).closest('.container');
        var _title = container.find('._title'),
        var _file = container.find('._file')[0]; 

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('SelectedFile', _file.files[0]);
        data.append('title', _title.value); 
        //Rest of your code
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Good answer - although the jQuery object doesn't have a `files` array, so you need `_file[0].files[0]`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan check my answer please.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki your answer puts all the available inputs in the `FormData` as opposed to just those related to the submit button which the user clicked - which I believe was the OP's intention.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers. I tried with this approach but getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined" on the line "data.append('SelectedFile' , _file[0].files[0])" . I googled it and there are a lot of questions about this error but i couldnt find any answer for my problem -> somehow i try to reach a undefined variable property.

Comment: @Mischu have you tried with `_file.files[0]`, note I have already defined `var _file = container.find('._file')[0];`

Comment: @Satpal Yes i have tried this, i will search for a solution :)

Comment: I found the error uuups. I have forgotten the dot for the class "container"   -> `$(this).closest('container');` instead of `$(this).closest('.container');`   Thanks to everybody who helped me with this issue.

Comment: And like you already mentioned:  `var _file = container.find('._file')[0].files[0]; `

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jquery you could use **[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** function and class selector `.` to loop through all the element with same class :

```
$('.class').each(function(){
    var input_value = $(this).val();
})
```

Since you have more than one field with class `_title` and `_file` you should pass them as array to `Formdata()` using array signs `[]` :

```
var data = new FormData();

$('._file').each(function(){
    var _file = $(this).val();
     data.append('SelectedFile[]', _file.files[0]);
})

$('._title').each(function(){
    var _title = $(this).val();
     data.append('title[]', _title);
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you can do a bit same as @satpal

Wrap your code in a div element.

**PHP:**

`foreach($db->query("SELECT id FROM news ORDER BY position ASC") as $row)
    {
    ...
    <div> <!-- wrapper -->
     <input type="text" class="_title" >
     Search: <input type="file" class="_file" >

     <input type='button' class="_submit" value='Save' > 
    </div>
    }
?>`

Then try following code.

**JS:**

```
$("._submit").click(function(){

    var title = $(this).siblings('._title').val();
    var file = $(this).siblings('._file')[0].files[0];

     var data = new FormData();
    data.append('SelectedFile',file);
    data.append('title', title); 
});
```

The above code makes use of `.siblings()` function